# why this code don't work ?(pandas successful install)

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

a = [1, 7, 2]

myvar = pd.Series(a)

print(myvar)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you really installed Pandas into your Python?

Comment: I use cmd to install pandas (pip)

Comment: Perhaps the directory is not the same as your Python. Try to check it following this https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you do not have pandas installed in your environment.

You need to install pandas either with pip, conda, or from source.